# How to set QMenu tear-off window title?

Tags: python, pyqt5, titlebar, qmenu, pyside2

I'm creating a custom ui in Maya 2017 which uses PyQt5 (well... technically PySide2, but it's essentially the same).

I've got a few `CustomContextMenu` popup menus that I've created in my ui and I've used `popup.setTearOffEnabled(True)` to be able to tear them off into a separate window (popup, being the QMenu item).

I cannot seem to figure out how to set the title for the resulting torn off window. Currently, each torn off window is titled "Maya-2017", but I'd like to give it a unique name for clarity. I've noticed that Maya's menu items with tear off functionality name the resulting window with the menu's name, so it would seem this is doable. Am I just missing something obvious?

I have tried using `popup.setTitle('test name')` on the QMenu thinking it would then name the tear off window this title, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Other than that, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether torn-off menus appear the same on all platforms, but on my Linux system, they are shown as tool windows with a title-bar. So the title can be set like this:

```
menu = QMenu('File')
menu.setTearOffEnabled(True)
menu.setWindowTitle('File')
```

Comment: awesome - this is exactly what I needed; don't know how I missed that command